# replace object by id within an object and keep the same key in database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

FoundUser is the user with the id that a new item will be added to that specific users items array.

```
const FoundUser = Object.keys(users)
  .map(key => users[key])
  .find(item => item.uid === uid)
console.log(FoundUser, 'current obj user')
```

UpUser is the updated FoundUser object with an item added to that specific users items array.

```
const itemobj = { name: "addeditem", price:330 }
const UpUser = {...FoundUser, items:FoundUser.items.concat([itemobj])}
console.log(UpUser, 'UpUser')
```

How do I only update the object of that same user in my original `users` object without removing the unique key `"97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2"`.

```
const final = Object.assign({}, )
console.log(final, 'final')
```

The users data looks like this.

```
state= {
{ "97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2": 
  {
   email:"some email", 
   items:[{name:'rose sherpa', price: 250}], 
   uid:'97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2',
   username:'someusername'
  },
  "47gbLdr412312312yyZljL75o2": 
  {
   email:"some email2", 
   items:[{name:'black sherpa', price: 350}], 
   uid:'97gbLdr4yy1231123VyoJraPo2',
   username:'someusername2'
  } 
 }
}
```

Desired Output is

```
{"97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2": 
 {
  email:"some email", 
  items:[{name:'rose sherpa', price: 250} , {name:'addeditem', price:330}], 
  uid:'97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2',
  username:'someusername'
 },
 "47gbLdr412312312yyZljL75o2": 
 {
  email:"some email2", 
  items:[{name:'black sherpa', price: 350}], 
  uid:'97gbLdr4yy1231123VyoJraPo2',
  username:'someusername2'
 } 
}
```

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be similar to how you update `items` of `FoundUser`:

```
const final = { ...users, [FoundUser.uid]: UpUser }
```

Btw `Object.keys(users).map(key => users[key])` can be simplified to `Object.values(users)`.

Comment: @Omar can you elaborate what are these 2 new objects?

Comment: @Omar so what do you think `final` will be? With reference to the example given above (assuming FoundUser is the user with uid `97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2`).

Comment: I do not know why that was happening i debugged the code and could not figure out why it was adding new user objects while also updating the current. This all looks like it should work.

Comment: There's probably something else wrong. Add in the code and the console output of the variables.

Comment: i think i know what it was ill get back to you going to re-test it right now if it works ill accept the answer

Comment: okay yes figured it out it had to do with changing a param in rebase

Answer (score 1):

I might fold that all into a single function:

```js
const users = {"47gbLdr412312312yyZljL75o2": {"email": "some email2", "items": [{"name": "black sherpa", "price": 350}], "uid": "97gbLdr4yy1231123VyoJraPo2", "username": "someusername2"}, "97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2": {"email": "some email", "items": [{"name": "rose sherpa", "price": 250}], "uid": "97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2", "username": "someusername"}}

const addItem = (item, uid, users) => 
  Object.values(users).find(user => user.uid === uid).items.push(item)


addItem({name:'addeditem', price:330}, '97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2', users)

console.log(users)
```

Or if you can't guarantee that the user you want will be included in the list, then

```
const addItem = (item, uid, users) => {
  const user = Object.values(users).find(user => user.uid === uid)
  if (user) {user.items.push(item)}
  return users
}
```

(And of course there might be another check if `user.items` might not exist.)

I actually have a preference for immutable data, and would for my own use probably craft a solution using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/). (disclaimer: I'm a Ramda author)

```js
const {map, when, propEq, evolve, append} = R

const users = {"47gbLdr412312312yyZljL75o2": {"email": "some email2", "items": [{"name": "black sherpa", "price": 350}], "uid": "97gbLdr4yy1231123VyoJraPo2", "username": "someusername2"}, "97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2": {"email": "some email", "items": [{"name": "rose sherpa", "price": 250}], "uid": "97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2", "username": "someusername"}}


const addItem = (item, uid, users) => 
  map(when(propEq('uid', uid), evolve({items: append(item)})), users)


const newUsers = addItem({name:'addeditem', price:330}, '97gbLdr4yyZljL75aZeVyoJraPo2', users)

console.log(newUsers)
console.log(users) // unchanged
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```